# Principal Component Analysis in QGIS

Tags: qgis, remote-sensing, satellite

How do I go about to perform a band ratio and Principal Component analysis in QGIS? I need to derive principal components from ratios of landsat TM bands .

Comment: If you have GRASS GIS, it's easy [i.pca](http://grass.osgeo.org/grass65/manuals/i.pca.html)

Comment: I would like to reply in detail on this. However, I don't understand the point behind deriving _Principal Components from ratios_. Elaborating on a simple example, you mean like: calculate **Ratio 1 =** `Band 4 / Band 3`, calculate **Ratio 2 =** `Band 4 / (Band 4 + Band 3)`, then derive PCs from Ratio 1 & Ratio 2?